# Self-hosted WCF needs to start a process as a user

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have several Windows Server boxes that I'm trying to get to do hard and long-running calculations.  I have installed on each of these machines a small WCF running as a Windows Service using net.tcp under the SYSTEM permissions.  I then have a central 'task master' that will send a JobDescription object (that I created) to allow these machines to perform their long task (a python script that takes a lot of resources and time).  To launch this I have the worker create a System.Diagnostic.Process and fill it in with all the parameters.  Upon completion the workers will notify the task master.

The problem that I am running into is that the python scrip needs to read and write to a network drive which has security settings so that the worker machines SYSTEM account can't read or write what is needed.  I tried going under the Windows Services tool and starting the worker machine process as a specific user, but then my task manager can't connect to the process anymore.  I get the following error:

```
     System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The
    communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel,
    cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
```

I've tried adding the identity tag to the task master .config file:

```
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="winntdom/name@company.com" />
    </identity>
```

Which has had basically no effect.

I am open to other ideas.  I'm basically beating my head against the keyboard at this point.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually.I had to take the address and modify it so I could connect to any of the computers in the cluster.  When I created a new endpoint in code I lost the identity from the `app.config` file.

OLD:

```
address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(String.Format@"net.tcp://{0}:8008/WorkerMachine/Daemon", machine_name));
```

`

NEW:

```
address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(
                    new Uri(String.Format(@"net.tcp://{0}:8008/WorkerMachine/Daemon", machine_name)),
                    EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("name@company.com"),
                    new System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressHeader[] { });
```